# Spring mvc ResourceBundleMessageSource for different themes

Tags: java, spring-mvc, themes

I configures my `appstrings.properties` file which contains strings related to theme used by my application. There are two themes for my application. Both have their own `appstrings.properties` file located at `WEB-INF/strings/theme1/appstrings` and `WEB-INF/strings/theme2/appstrings`. I specified property themeName in config.properties file.

Here is my spring config file:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:///${config.properties}" />

...

<bean id="messageSource"
class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"
p:basenames="WEB-INF/strings/theme1/appstrings" />
```

Right now all my app strings are coming from WEB-INF/strings/theme1/appstrings.properties file. How can I make it dynamic. i.e. when I change themeName propperty to theme2 it should get string from WEB-INF/strings/theme2/appstrings.properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If config.properties contains a property say: themeName = propertyValue. If you want to use this themeName's value in spring mvc configuration servlet xml file then you can use ${themeName}

```
<bean id="messageSource"
class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"
p:basenames="WEB-INF/strings/${themeName}/appstrings" />
```

[reference](http://www.imrantariq.com/blog/?p=678)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `ResourceBundleThemeSource`

```
<!-- resolves localized <theme_name>.properties files in the classpath to 
    allow for theme support -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.ui.context.support.ResourceBundleThemeSource"
    id="themeSource" /> 
 <mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.ThemeChangeInterceptor"/> 
 </mvc:interceptors>
```

See [Spring Reference Chapter 15.7 Using Themes](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#mvc-themeresolver)

For an running example you can quickly create a small Spring Roo application. It uses the theme support to change the css files.